# How to access a particular column in this json field element?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is the schema of the json file that I've loaded into the dataframe. I want to filter out the data where the data in this column doesn't contain any elements
[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5KlH.png)

```
root
 |-- children: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- children: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- children: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- parent_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- recursive: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- shared: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- parent_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- recursive: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- shared: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- parent_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- recursive: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- shared: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- created_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- last_modified_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- links: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order: long (nullable = true)
 |-- parent_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- pid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- project_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- recursive: boolean (nullable = true)
```

I tried accessing the data column using

```
df.filter("children = array('')").show()
```

but was getting the following error

> cannot resolve '(children = array(''))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(children = array(''))' (array<structchildren:array<struct<children:array<struct<created_date:string,description:string,id:bigint,last_modified_date:string,links:array<struct<href:string,rel:string>,name:string,order:bigint,parent_id:bigint,pid:string,recursive:boolean,shared:boolean>>,created_date:string,description:string,id:bigint,last_modified_date:string,links:array<structhref:string,rel:string>,name:string,order:bigint,parent_id:bigint,pid:string,recursive:boolean,shared:boolean>>,created_date:string,description:string,id:bigint,last_modified_date:string,links:array<structhref:string,rel:string>,name:string,order:bigint,parent_id:bigint,pid:string,recursive:boolean,shared:boolean>> and array).;

Comment: you'll need to give us a way to load your data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `size("children") != 0`? See https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.size.html

Comment: If we can somehow get the length of this field, that'll also work.